# A dozen countdowns in jQuery refreshing every second.

Tags: javascript, countdown

I want make a dozen of dynamic countdowns. I have countdown's time end in php table: "timeend[]" and file timeend.php return like: 2012-12-31 04:00:00;2012-12-30 02:00:00;...
I had javascript code but it work with one countdown: http://pastebin.com/2dih5XVC 
Who know how to make many dynamic countdowns???

P.s Sorry for bad English but I'm Polish

Comment: why did you tag this with "php" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [this jQuery plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) you can just used `$(selector).countdown({since: new Date(2010, 12-1, 25)});` to add a new countdown. Using different selectors results in different countdowns.